# Are skin moles linked to telomere length?

Tags: dermatology

[BBC: Skin moles link to delayed ageing](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-11813378)

> The reason for these links are unclear, but researchers have noticed that people with large numbers of moles have differences in the strands of DNA in each cell which carry their genetic code.
>
> Sections on the end of these strands are called telomeres, and are effectively a countdown timer governing the number of times a cell can divide to produce new cells.
>
> The longer the telomere, the more cell divisions can take place over a lifetime - and **more moles were linked to longer telomeres**.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) That artice does *not* talk about longevity, and "slower age rate" doesn't really mean anything. There are a several different claims in the article: moles are correlated with: skin cells that divide more often, better bone density, and longer telomeres. I will choose one to edit in to keep this answer open.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18161/do-people-with-more-moles-live-longer